# Problem Loading Binary File Into MySQL BLOB

Tags: mysql, file, binary, blob

I need help loading binary data from a file into MySQL (M)BLOB field.  Windows 10 and XAMPP.

I get a strange screen full of errors when I try to load a .bin file into MySQL database MBLOB field using myphpadmin.  Among other stuff I see a partial SQL statement trying to assign a value of "0x0000000000000..." and off the screen.  The final line in the response is like “2006: MySQL server has gone away”. The file is ~500kB long.  I tested uploading a .jpg that was over 1MB which worked fine, so it's not a size limit thing.

The file was created by a C program and stores raw byte values from an unsigned char array with no formatting or headers.  It does begin with several dozen 0 values if that matters.  BTW, I named the file with .bin not knowing any better.

Comment: please show your code and look for threads with images, you need probably to convert it back from base64 back

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what code to show.  I have a .bin file and I use the myPhpAdmin interface to load from a file picker.  That's when it fails.

Comment: that is not information that you provided, please clarify your question wth all details, still the base64 could be the problem

Comment: When you want to load binary file into BLOB column then you must use `LOAD_FILE()` function.